# Using wildcard ssl certificate for Spring Boot backend

Tags: security, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, server-configuration

I have acquired a wildcard SSL certificate from my hoster (Hoster X) for my domain, e.g. domain.com.

Now I have a Spring Boot Backend running on Server A (Not hosted at Hoster X, IP: 1.1.1.1, URL: api.domain.com) and my Frontend running on another Server B (Hosted at Hoster X, IP:2.2.2.2, URL app.domain.com).

The redirection of api.domain.com to the IP 1.1.1.1 is set via an A Resource Record in the DNS configuration of Hoster X because domain.com is registered here.

### [image]

What's the general approach here to install the certificate on my Spring Boot Backend so that the communication between my Frontend and Backend is secured? Do I have to download the wildcard certificate to install it into the backends keystore? For what I can tell I can only configure the SSL certificate in my hosters menu on domains which are hosted on Hoster X Servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the backend server, merge the private key file, the certificate file and the CA file into a pkcs12 keystore with openssl and the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <certfile> -inkey <keyfile> -out <keystorefile> -name tomcat -CAfile <cacertfile> -caname root
```

You are prompted to enter a keystore password. Now copy the generated keystore file (extension 'p12') to the Spring Boot application's resources directory.

Now set the Spring Boot SSL configuration in the application.yml:

```
server:
    port: 8443

# Spring SSL configuration
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
        key-store-password: "<KeystorePassword>"
        keyStoreType: PKCS12
        keyAlias: tomcat
```

Alternatively, copy the keystore.p12 somewhere on the backend server and point to the location with the absolute path:

```
server:
    ssl:
        key-store: /path/to/keystore.p12
```

It is important to create an A Record in the DNS settings on the Frontend machine, so that all Frontend requests to the Backend go via a call to the domain and not the IP since the wildcard certificate is only valid for the domain.